# Welcome page not closing on perspective change

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application in which i have added the Intro page (welcome page). This is implemented using the IIntroPart. so mine is not an xml oriented welcome page.

Problem: when the application is started the welcome page is displayed perfectly. But now when the welcome page is still opened (visible), if i try to open a perspective in my application, the welcome page is not moving towards right (as it does in Eclipse IDE) making space for the perspective that i have selected.

So even after selecting the perspective, the perspective is not shown and the welcome page is still occupying the entire workbench area. Please note that, the selected perspectve is NOT hiding behind the welcome page. But the selected perspective is getting updated in the perspective shortcuts!

On restart (after clearing the metadata) if i manually close the welcome page and then try to open the perspective, the perspective just opens fine.

It is because of the welcome page (when it is visible) the selected perspective is not opening in the workbench.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue? It should behave just like the way the welcome page behaves in Eclipse IDE. i.e, when the welcome page is still opened, if a perspective is opened, then the welcome page should move right making space for the pespective and hence both (the selected perspective and the welcome page) should be visible.

UPDATE:

Some progress on the issue. Now when i select a perspective to open ("window -> open perspective -> MyPerspective") when the welcome page (intro part) is still opened, am able to close the welcome page (this is done by adding the part listener to the welcome page). But now an empty area is displayed and the perspective is not shown. However, the selected perspective is getting updated in the applications Perspective shortcut bar

Any help is welcomed...

Comment: which eclipse version you are using..?

Comment: The eclipse version is 3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Add the perspective listeners and minimize the welcome page. Put the below code in Activator start method.

```java
    final IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    workbench.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().addPerspectiveListener(new IPerspectiveListener() {

                    public void perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage arg0, IPerspectiveDescriptor arg1) {
                        // Nothing to do

                    }

                    public void perspectiveChanged(IWorkbenchPage arg0, IPerspectiveDescriptor arg1, String arg2) {

                        // Fix for bug number 8028
                        IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
                        IViewPart introView = page.findView("org.eclipse.ui.internal.introview");//$NON-NLS-1$
                        if (introView != null && page.getReference(introView) != null) {
                            int currentState = page.getPartState(page.getReference(introView));
                            if (currentState != IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED) {
                                page.setPartState(page.getReference(introView), IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });                
        }
    });
```